# Action not being dispatched from effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, effects

I have this effect below, which executes fine as I get the tokens I need. But it does not kick off the new effect `newUserRequested` I am new to Ngrx and am struggling with how to wire up `effects`.

```
  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login),
    switchMap(action => {
      console.log(action.payload)
      localStorage.setItem(`access_token`, action.payload.accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem(`refresh_token`, action.payload.refreshToken);
      return of(new UserRequested());
    }),
  );
```

```
  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  loadUser$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<UserRequested>(AuthActionTypes.UserRequested),
      tap(res => console.log('user requested' ,res)),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(isUserLoaded))),
      filter(([action, _isUserLoaded]) => !_isUserLoaded),
      mergeMap(([action, _isUserLoaded]) => {
        return this.auth.getUserFromToken()
          .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
              of(new AuthError({error: err}));
              return EMPTY;
            }),
            switchMap(user => {
              if (user) {
                const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
                const authUser: AuthUser = jsonConvert.deserializeObject(user, AuthUser);
                console.log(authUser)
                return of(new UserLoaded({user: authUser}));
              }
            })
          )
      }));
```

Init effect

```
  @Effect()
  init$: Observable<Action> = defer(() => {

    const aToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    const rToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

    if (aToken) {
      return of(new Login({accessToken: aToken, refreshToken: rToken}));
    } else {
      return of({type: 'NO_ACTION'});
    }
  });
```

Do my effects look ok?

Comment: try removing `dispatch:false` - you are telling ngrx that these effects won't dispatch actions, when they do and you need them to for your next effect to fire.

Comment: Indeed, an obvious one. The `dispatch:false` property needs to be ommitted for this use case.

Comment: does that resolve your issue?